# Import OSMAND tracks in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, gpx, osmand

I would like to import GPS tracks created in osmand to QGIS. 
First, I exported the tracks in gpx format from OSMand. then I tried using the vector-->GPS tools --> load GPX file dialog. The file is accepted and the layer created but does not show and the attribute table is empty as well (only contains the name but no trackpoints).

Loading gpx files form osmand works in JOSM and ArcGIS but not in QGIS. Any ideas about how to get it to work?

Comment: can you upload a sample file?

Comment: When importing a GPX file, QGIS makes choose between different data types (points, track points, routes, tracks), even if the GPX file doesn't contain all of those types. Are you sure you chose the correct option?